# find a partition of Z into 10 infinite sets? For each partition, what is the corresponding equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I need to find a
partition of Z into 10 infinite sets, and for each partition, what is the
corresponding equivalence relation?

so I know there's a theorem that states "**let P be a partition of a nonempty set A. Then there exists an equivalence relation R on A such that P is the set of equivalence classes determined by R**"

So an obvious partition of the set of integers that is infinite and is in 10 parts is the set that is 10k and another set 10k+1,...,10k+9 for an integer k.

But how can I find the corresponding relation?

Comment: The theorem you mention tells you you can define it just as being equivalence iff they are in the same element of the partition. For this specific partition, that translates to both give the same $n$ when written as $10k+n$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Thanks, I'm sorry I didn't get that, specifically what you meant by "you can define it just as being equivalence"  what exactly do you mean by to be equivalence?

Comment: Typo or language barrier.  They are saying that you can define the relation to be such that two numbers are related iff they come from the same part in the partition.  The partition defines a relation, in exactly the same way as a relation defines a partition.  If you have the one you have the other and vice versa.

Comment: Granted, there can also be *other* ways to write certain relations and/or partitions.  The partition you refer to could have had its relation defined as $x$ is related to $y$ iff $x-y$ is a multiple of $10$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh ok, that makes perfect sense thanks!